# Make the cell fit the text (and make it read-only)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I started using TkinterTable and I'm baby-stepping in Tkinter functionalities, so I'm very noob. I'm trying to display some data from some sources but my concern is that the cells seem to be shorter than the text and I can't find a way to make the cells fit the text size. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkintertable import TableCanvas, TableModel

data = {'1': {'Source': 'OB', 'Campaign': 'X7765LKBTYYU-TAB-US', 'Impr.': 9457123, 'CTR': '0.12%', 'Spent': 45.78},
       '2': {'Source': 'OB', 'Campaign': 'X6159TNFYTHY-PHONE-US-A', 'Impr.': 5456953, 'CTR': '0.27%', 'Spent': 12.52},
       '3': {'Source': 'OB', 'Campaign': 'X7765LGKJHYRT-TAB-US', 'Impr.': 9457123, 'CTR': '0.12%', 'Spent': 45.78},
       '4': {'Source': 'OB', 'Campaign': 'X6159FTJKYUKKX-PHONE-US-A', 'Impr.': 5456953, 'CTR': '0.27%', 'Spent': 12.52}
       } 

root= Tk()
tframe = Frame(root)
tframe.pack()
model = TableModel()
table = TableCanvas(tframe, model=model, data=data, editable=False, width=800, height=300)
table.show()
root.mainloop()
```

BTW, not my main problem, but if you have a quick fix it would be appreciated. You'll notice that I've "editable=False" in TableCanvas but that doesn't seem to make the cell read-only, I still can edit them. Any idea why?

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source py:

```
class TableCanvas(Canvas):
    """A tkinter class for providing table functionality"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, model=None, data=None, read_only=False,
                 width=None, height=None,
                 rows=10, cols=5, **kwargs):
    ...

    def adjustColumnWidths(self):
        """Optimally adjust col widths to accomodate the longest entry
            in each column - usually only called  on first redraw"""

        ...

    def autoResizeColumns(self):
        """Automatically set nice column widths and draw"""

        ...
```

For your first question, it looks like the `adjustColumnWidths` method is not dealing with long strings properly (maybe platform specific?). Without digging too much into it, the easiest way is to overwrite the method:

```
class CustomCanvas(TableCanvas):
    def adjustColumnWidths(self):
        try:
            fontsize = self.thefont[1]
        except:
            fontsize = self.fontsize
        scale = 8.5 * float(fontsize)/12
        for col in range(self.cols):
            colname = self.model.getColumnName(col)
            if colname in self.model.columnwidths:
                w = self.model.columnwidths[colname]
            else:
                w = self.cellwidth
            maxlen = self.model.getlongestEntry(col)
            size = maxlen * scale
            if size < w:
                continue
            #if size >= self.maxcellwidth:
            #    size = self.maxcellwidth
            self.model.columnwidths[colname] = size*1.2 #I changed the calculation to a static float
        return
```

And then use `CustomCanvas` as a replacement to your `TableCanvas`.

For the editable part, not sure where you get the idea to pass `editable` as a parameter. If you use `read_only=True` it should work as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed the "read_only" did it. But the "adjustColumnWidths" I took a look at it this afternoon but I had no clue how to apply it. I tried a couple of things but it keeps telling me "adjustColumnWidths" is  not defined. For the editable it was in the documentation.

Comment: From the looks of it, should be simply `table.adjustColumnWidths()` and `table.autoResizeColumns()`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work : table.adjustColumnWidths()
table.autoResizeColumns()
table.redraw()

Comment: You are the Man. Thank you very much.

Comment: On 2nd look I realize that the `maxcellwidth` is actually an implementation. If you don't like the limitation, you can comment it out as edited above and have the size grow accordingly for a more generic appoarch.

Comment: well for me that read_only=True work.

table = TableCanvas(tframe, read_only=True)

Comment: @HenryYik  Is there any option to make the autofit column option as default?